# Autocomplete numa célula de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, table, autocompletar

Estou com dificuldades em adaptar [este](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) exemplo de autocomplete à minha tabela. Pretendo colocar o autocomplete na célula da designação. O que se passa é o seguinte:

**HTML TABLE**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="vendaTabela" width="100%" >
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th data-class="expand">Cód.</th>
     <th data-hide="phone">Designação</th>
     <th data-hide="phone">Qnt.</th>
     <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Uni.</th>
     <th>Preço</th>
     <th>Desconto</th>
     <th>IVA</th>
     <th>Sub-Total</th>
     <th></th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr id="tr0">
     <td class="codigo" contenteditable="true" onblur="codArtigo ( )"></td>
     <td id="tags" class="designacao" contenteditable="true" onblur="nomeArtigo()"></td>
     <td class="quantidade" contenteditable="true" onblur="subtotal ( )"></td>
     <td class="unidade" contenteditable="false"></td>
     <td class="preco" contenteditable="true"></td>
     <td class="desconto" contenteditable="true"></td>
     <td class="iva" contenteditable="false"></td>
     <td class="total" contenteditable="false"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC"

        ];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
        });
```

Até aqui tudo bem a questão é que ao colocar o 'id="tags"' no 'td' da designação, estraga-me o layout da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faz-me ali um género de colapsan da designação com a quantidade. Alguém sabe o que poderá ser?

**EDIT**

Ao inspecionar elemento, ele está a adicionar um :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há maneira de "fugir" a isso ?

Comment: Testei aqui no JSFiddle seu código e pareceu perfeito. http://jsfiddle.net/br9xx888/

Comment: Estranho, então terá a ver com o layout da minha tabela não ?! O autocomplete aparece-me, mas o layout é que fica todo torto :s

Comment: Percebo que há uma coluna a menos em seu tbody, alguma coluna é adicionada dinamicamente? Pois mesmo sem uma das colunas o layout se comportaria bem. Só ficaria uma coluna em branco. Existe algum javascript adicionando propriedades colspan por exemplo na sua tabela? Inspecione pelo console do navegador e veja o que está acontecendo... Não sei o que pode ser, então chuto possibilidades...

Comment: Isso foi a copiar para aqui, essa coluna de facto existe e tem um botão :) as colunas coincidem

Comment: No html gerado, você inspecionou se não está sendo criado com algum tipo de colspan ? Talvez adicionado por javascript por exemplo?

Comment: Está a criar-me um span. Fiz um edit na pergunta. Sabe como eliminar isso ? Obrigado desde já pela ajuda

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791984/jquery-ui-autocomplete-adding-a-span aqui está uma possível solução

Comment: onde é que coloco mesmo isso? .ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display:none; }

Comment: Já consegui, muito obrigado ;)

Comment: Desculpe vi agora seus comentários, mas que bom que resolveu seu problema.